# repeating WaitForSingleObject in messages between to applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, message, waitforsingleobject

I created two programs in C (producer and consumer) which send messages the one to each other
(using CreateEvent, SetEvent and WaitForSingleObject)

I implement one thread for each program to manages this messages 
using WaitForSingleObject(myEvent, INFINITE) waiting for a message

I put the  WaitForSingleObject in looping to repeat and obtain many messages in time.

This works fine in the first time but the other times the  WaitForSingleObject not wait for a message and the left code run in infinitive loops (including again the WaitForSingleObject)

I tested to remove CloseHandle(myEvent) both of two programs but without results

```
do {
//wait until the event received from another process
WaitForSingleObject(myrcvEvent, INFINITE);

//send the feeback event, if it is failed show a message
printf ("consumer: try to send the feedback event\n");
if (!SetEvent(myfeedbackEvent)) {
msgbox("consumer: Set feedbackEvent failed!");
        return;
 } else {

InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE); //redraw with new values
 }


//CloseHandle(myrcvEvent);
//CloseHandle(myfeedbackEvent);

Sleep(100);
} while(1);
```

What is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What about the rest - where myrcvEvent is created and the producer code?  What you have posted seems OK-ish as it stands, though it seems odd to perform this loop in what appears to be a GUI thread?  When you have fixed your inter-thread comms issue, I assume you'll dump the sleep(100).

Comment: For both events, don't use manual reset and set initial state to false.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an event for this?  Use a semaphore - CreateSemaphore() API.

Even when using an, (inappropriate), event for this signaling, I would not expect continual looping as a symptom with one producer, one consumer and an auto reset event - post your code.

Comment: Is an exercise for my university and is requirement. I posted the code, thanks

Comment: Tell your tutor/prof that it is a silly use for an event when a more suitable synchronization primitive is available, (and do the inappropriate event-based code as well).